# get all <h2> tag and <p> tag text from mysql text datatype column

Tags: php, mysql, dom

I am trying to split and fetch p tag and h2 tag texts from database. I have tried this below code. it returns first result only. For example in my database I have

```
<h2>india</h2><p>country</p><h2>dravid</h2><p>cricket player</p>
```

I want to fetch h2 results and para results separately. but this below code returns first h2 and para results only. How do I get all h2 tag and p tag text from database?

```
$getdata = $res['review_content'];
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($getdata); // loads your html
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$heading = $xpath->evaluate("string(//h2/text())");
// paragraph text
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($getdata); // loads your html
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$paragraph = $xpath->evaluate("string(//p/text())");
```

When I tried `echo $heading` it returns India only. But I want to display India and Dravid

Comment: Show us the output you want to see.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code, it will first parse the html into object,

then we are searching for specific element by there tag name  `getElementsByTagName` and getting the content of the tag by `textContent` function

```
            <?php


               $getdata = '<h2>india</h2><p>country</p><h2>dravid</h2><p>cricket player</p>';
                $doc = new DOMDocument();
                libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

                $pTag = array();
                $h2Tag= array();
                $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
                $xmlDoc->loadHTML($getdata);    
                $searchNode = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName("p");

                 foreach($searchNode as $d){
                   $pTag[] =  $d->textContent;
                 }

                $searchNode = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName("h2");

                 foreach($searchNode as $d){
                   $h2Tag[] =  $d->textContent;
                 }

                // pTag[] contain array of content all p tag                    
                // h2Tag[] contain array of content all h2 tag                  
            ?>
```

Comment: how do I echo $pTag properly (outside of foreach loop).

Comment: This `$pTag` contain all the p element content, you can use `print_r($pTag)` to check it's content outside the loop

Comment: yes I have checked that. How do echo those datas properly

Comment: To get the data in string form you can use `echo implode(' ' , $pTag)` . 
 
 More clearly you can use a for loop again to 
   
                `foreach($pTag as $d){ echo  $d; }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [getElementsByTagName](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php).

Example:

```
$h2 = $doc->getElementsByTagName('h2');
$p = $doc->getElementsByTagName('p');
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should try this code it will help you get your desired result.

```
$db_string=html_entity_decode($file_contents);


    $doc = new DOMDocument();
            $doc->loadXML( $db_string );//string goes here from database
            $para= $doc->getElementsByTagName( "p" );
            $a= $doc->getElementsByTagName( "a" );
            foreach($para as $p_tag){
                $para_values = $p_tag->item(0)->nodeValue;
            }
            foreach($a as $a_tag){
                $a_values = $a_tag->item(0)->nodeValue;
            }
```

Comment: In Foreach loop you can use your own logic if you want to save the values for later use.